# How to declare single and double quote in a json string?

Tags: json

I have declared a property in my json file of string type and I have both single and double quotes inside that string like below-

```
{
"height": "5' 8" "
}
```

So, now it is showing some error. How should I write that?

Comment: `"5' 8 inch\" "`

Comment: You can escape special characters with a backslash, e.g.: "5' 8 inch\" "

Comment: Noting that saying "inch" *and* using the symbol is redundant.

Answer (score 5):

The single quote is not an issue, you have to escape the double quote like this:

```
{
"height": "5' 8 inch\" "
}
```

See the spec: http://json.org

Answer (score 1):

Below format should work for you. As your Json element has double quote inside the actual string, you can use backslash escape character.

```
{
"height": "5' 8 inch\" "
}
```

For more details, you can refer the link.
https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html